# import mysql database from local to remote server

Tags: mysql, linux, cron, azure-mysql-database

i would like to import a dumped local database into a remote "*azure database for mysql server*" using **cronjob**.

in terminal it works fine with this command:

```
mysql -u[USER] -p[PASSWORD] -h[REMOTE-HOST] --ssl-mode=REQUIRED --ssl-ca=sslCert/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem remotedb < localdb.sql
```

it also works, if i put that command in a shell script and call it manually.

why doesn't it work within **/etc/crontab**?

```
### import db into azure mysql server ###
*/3 * * * * itsme  /home/itsme/backup/app/dumps/import_db_into_remote.sh
```

the same happens if i'm trying to dump a database from remote to local via cron. it does not work.

Comment: Is your cron user account allowed to do a backup and/or restore

Comment: Do you have #!/bin/bash at the top of the script?

Comment: This may seem basic, but maybe it needs executable perms:
`chmod +x /home/itsme/backup/app/dumps/import_db_into_remote.sh`

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
yes. it's the same user as in the crontab.
user: itsme

Comment: @RamanSailopal
yes

Comment: @Xinthral
not even chmod 777 works.

Comment: issue resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay before doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved.
cron needs the complete path to the certificate file

mysql -u[USER] -p[PASSWORD] -h[REMOTE-HOST] --ssl-mode=REQUIRED --ssl-ca=**/home/itsme/backup/app/sslCert/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem** remotedb < localdb.sql